# V-for not displaying records after his has fetched on console

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2

I have init the array ArtificialInsemination[]  on response received but its not showing or loading the records in the table. When I click the button its calls the functions viewRecords and sends the HTTP request successfully, but not loading into the table.

```
<div id="ArtificialInsemination" class="container">
        <button v-on:click="viewRecords">View Record</button>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Cow Id</th>
                <th>Bull Name</th>
                <th>Semen Origin</th>
                <th>Insemination Time</th>
                <th>Pd Delivery Date</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr v-for ="artificialInseminationRecord in artificialInseminationRecords">
                <td>{{ artificialInseminationRecord.cowId }}</td>
                <td>{{ artificialInseminationRecord.bullUsedName }}</td>
                <td>{{ artificialInseminationRecord.semenOrigin }}</td>
                <td>{{ artificialInseminationRecord.inseminationTime }}</td>
                <td>{{ artificialInseminationRecord.pdStatusDate }}</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

This is the vue

```
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.0.3/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@0.12.0/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/lodash@4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.debug.js"></script>

<script>
    //class initialization

    var ArtificialInsemination = new Vue({
        el:'#ArtificialInsemination',
        data: {
            url:'http://localhost/dairyfarm/index.php',
            artificialInseminationRecords: []

        },
        //invoke methods
        methods: {
          viewRecords:function () {
              var data = new FormData()
              data.append('function','viewRecords')
              axios.post(this.url,data)
                  .then( function (response ) {
                  this.artificialInseminationRecords = response.data.data
              }).catch(function (error) {

              })

            },
            created: function(){
              this.viewRecords()

            }
        }
    })

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a scoping issue, `this` inside a callback refers to the execution context of the callback not the Vue instance. You need to either assign `this` to something outside the callback:

```
// assign this to self
var self = this;
axios.post(this.url,data)
  .then( function (response ) {
      self.artificialInseminationRecords = response.data.data
}).catch(function (error) {

})
```

Or use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which do not create their own execution context:

```
axios.post(this.url,data)
  .then( response => {
      this.artificialInseminationRecords = response.data.data
}).catch(function (error) {

})
```

Answer (score 1):

You decided to use `created` event, but you defined it as a method. :)

Look at this sample:
[Async Data Mutation inside of Created Event](https://jsfiddle.net/qu1yy5gd/)

Answer (score 1):

We only needed to add bind like this

```
   viewRecords:function () {
          var data = new FormData()
          data.append('function','viewRecords')
          axios.post(this.url,data)
              .then( function (response ) {
              this.artificialInseminationRecords = response.data.data
          }.bind(this)).catch(function (error) {

          })

        }
```

Comment: If you're using ES2015 I recommend that you use the arrow function option. It was introduced to prevent you having to bind `this` all over the place, which can be a little verbose.